# Runtime error in Graph Program created using c++

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph, adjacency-list

I am trying to create a program to represent Graph using Adjacency List. In that I have created a menu-driven program and implemented non-class functions to create the graph, create edges between the vertices and to display the graph.
The main question is to represent a map of area in the form of graph and use single characters (like 'a','b' or 'c' etc) to represent the cities. Following is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Graph
{
    public:
    char city;
    int distance;
    Graph *next;
};

Graph **graph=new Graph*[20];
int size;

void display()
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        Graph *temp=graph[i];
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            cout<<temp->city<<"--"<<temp->distance<<"--";
            if(temp->next==NULL)
            cout<<"NULL"<<endl;
        }
    }
}

void edges()
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            if(i==j)
            continue;
            
            Graph *temp=graph[i],*node=new Graph;
            char input;
            cout<<"\nIs there connection between " << graph[i]->city << " and " << graph[j]->city << "? Enter y or n: ";
            cin>>input;
            if(input=='y' || input=='Y')
            {
                cout<<"\nEnter the distance between them:";
                cin>>node->distance;
                temp->next=node;
                temp=temp->next;
                temp->next=NULL;
            }
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"Edges Created Successfully\n";
    
}

void create()
{
    cout<<"Enter the number of cities:";
    cin>>size;
    cout<<"Enter "<<size<<" cities\n";
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        cout<<"City number "<<i+1<<":";
        cin>>graph[i]->city;
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        int choice;
        cout<<"\n1.Create a graph\n";
        cout<<"2.Create the connections between the vertices\n";
        cout<<"3.Display the graph\n";
        cout<<"4.Exit\n";
        cout<<"Enter your choice:";
        cin>>choice;
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
            create();
            break;
            
            case 2:
            edges();
            break;
            
            case 3:
            display();
            break;
            
            case 4:
            exit(0);
            break;
            
            default:
            cout<<"Invalid Choice"<<endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is : Whenever I run the program, the program terminates unexpectedly after taking 3rd city as input. It does not allow me to take further inputs as well as to perform other operations.
Please help me as this error is quite new to me. I think the cause of the error might be due to dynamically created Graph pointers array. But it is just a guess and I do not know the real cause of this problem.

Comment: `Graph **graph=new Graph*[20];` creates an array of 20 `Graph*`'s.  Where do you ever set those pointers to point to actual `Graph` object you have created?

Comment: You know `char city;` declares a single character like `'A'`? Seems you might want `std::string` there.

Comment: *In that I have created a menu-driven program * -- Honestly, you should have spent more time on seeing if the `Graph` actually works instead of menu systems.  You now have a mountain of irrelevant code to sift through.  As mentioned, you didn't do the proper setup of the pointers, but you concluded that you did.

Comment: Also, you have a class `Graph`, but the only way to use it is for the functions outside of `Graph` to manipulate the `Graph` internal members (for example, the `edges` function).  If you're going to create a `Graph` class, then it should have `public` member functions to add an edge,  The client using `Graph` would just call `Graph::add_edge(whatever)`, and thus not care *how* edges are created.   All of these things you missed out would have made the testing and debugging issues much more simpler, instead of wasting time making "menu systems".

Comment: My main focus is not the "menu-driven" program. I created it just for my understanding. If you wish I can change it. Obviously my main concern is the graph. Can you suggest me a better way to do it? Or atleast point out the mistake in the program. I have never dealt with array of pointers and so this error is new to me.

Comment: All of this is made much simpler if this was `std::map<char, std::vector<char>>` where the `char` is the vertex and the `std::vector<char>` are the vertices with an edge to the vertex.  For example: `{'c' {'a','b','x'}}` would mean the vertex `c` has an edge to vertices `a`, `b`, and `x`.  Then none of the pointers would be needed, no need for `new` anything, etc.

Comment: Also, if you want to include the distance: `std::map<char, std::vector<Node>>` where `Node` is a class that consists of the city and distance.  Again, no need for pointers, even in this case.

Comment: @challenger  *Bro, the task assigned asks me to use array of linked list only.* -- We have no idea what you can or cannot use.  Then in your previous comment, you stated this: `Can you suggest me a better way to do it?`.  Well, I suggested a better way.  Here is the issue -- you posted a lot of irrelevant code.  If the problem is the Graph, then boil this down to a simpler program, no menus, and just initialize the Graph and all its edges with *hard-coded* data that duplicates the issue.  As a matter of fact, that's how you should originally written the program -- bare bones.

Comment: For example,  start with `main`.  It should be only this: `int main() { create(); edges(); }`.  You don't care about users hitting `l` or `2`, or whatever.  That eliminates 95% of what was in `main` to do testing.  Then proceed and reduce `create()` and `edges` down to hard-coded data (instead of inputting data).

Comment: I tried using hard-coded data, but issue is the same. The program terminates unexpectedly without performing any task